# Error on zipping folders in applescript

Tags: zip, applescript

I'm trying to develop an automated script to zip up folders but I keep getting the following error:

```
error "Finder got an error: 
zip error: Nothing to do! (/Users/dam/Desktop/Design/_TEST/basefolder/Fonts.zip)" number 12
```

Been scouring the forums and not quite hitting the mark. Any help for a noob would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
tell application "Finder"
    set projFonts to (choose folder with prompt "Please select font folder.")
    set fontPath to quoted form of POSIX path of projFonts
    set zipName to the name of projFonts
    set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of projFonts as alias)
    set zipFile to the quoted form of (theFolder & zipName)
    do shell script "zip -j " & zipFile & " " & fontPath
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, although the question lacks details.

```
set theItem to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to set {fileName, theFolder} to {theItem's name, (theItem's container as text)'s POSIX path}
do shell script "zip -rj " & (theFolder & fileName & ".zip")'s quoted form & space & theItem's POSIX path's quoted form
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm working on a project automation script, and an aspect of it is taking all fonts and font folders from a 'root' folder and zipping them all together.

Comment: Okay, I hit a snag:

error " zip warning:   first full name: /Users/dam/Desktop/Design/_TEST/BourneUltimatum_4K_Wrap_White/Fonts/_MO_Fonts_Legend/MidnightOil_fonts/OTF/.DS_Store
                      second full name: /Users/dam/Desktop/Design/_TEST/BourneUltimatum_4K_Wrap_White/Fonts/Document fonts/.DS_Store
                     name in zip file repeated: .DS_Store
                     this may be a result of using -j

zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)" number 16

Comment: Additionally, I;d like to delete the source files after zipping them together (originals are backed up elsewhere, so I'm not worried about losing them).